# Як можна перекласти 'breaking change' українською?

Tags: переклад, from-english, терміни

Як можна перекласти '**breaking change**' українською?

Значення, укр.:

> Це зміна однієї частини програмної системи, яка потенційно може призвести до відмови інших компонентів; зустрічається найчастіше в бібліотеках спільного використання коду, який використовується декількома додатками.

Приклад, англ.:

> ...you should treat it as a **breaking change** and release a new major version of your library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Загалом *breaking changes* (у цьому значенні), по-моєму, є красивим синонімом до *backward incompatible changes*. Тож за змістом Ви, по-моєму, не помилитеся, якщо напишете ***зворотно несумісні зміни***. (Хоча в такому випадку виникає питання: «*не[ ]зворотно[ ]сумісні* чи *зворотно[ ]не[ ]сумісні*», але англійською теж існує два варіанти написання — *non[-, ]backward[-, ]compatible* і *backward[-, ]incompatible* — і з цих варіантів перевагу надають другому, тож я припускаю, так само має бути й в українській.)

Також українська мова має слова *[поворотний](http://sum.in.ua/s/povorotnyj)*, *[переламний](http://sum.in.ua/s/perelamnyj)*, *[переломний](http://sum.in.ua/s/perelomnyj)*, і за тлумаченнями вони наче підходять, але чи належна в них конотація, мені важко гарантувати.

Comment: `backward incompatible changes` і `breaking changes` - це трохи різні терміни, і це не синоніми ні в якому разі. 
`breaking changes` - це зміни, які "кладуть" якийсь компонент в системі, програмі або всю систему повністю. `breaking changes` "ламають" щось, змушуючи програму або її компоненти працювати неправильно або не працювати взагалі. Після цього зазвичай випускають хотфікси або екстренні патчі, бо важливі компоненти програми не працюють або не працюють так як треба.

Comment: `backward incompatible changes` - це зміни в новій версії(версіях) програмі(якщо ми говоримо про програмування), які унеможливлюють використання цих нових версій наприклад на старому "залізі"/ програмному середовищі(ОС), прошивці(телефони), пристроях і тд. Наприклад, якщо програму переводять на нову версію мови програмування, розробники вже не можуть забезпечити сумісність з телефонами версії версії x.x, хоча до цього така сумісність була. Це і є `backward incompatible changes`.

Comment: `breaking changes` зазвичай ламають опосередковано, тобто зміна в одній частині програми  "кладе" іншу. У нових версіях фреймворків та third party libraries часто є список `breaking changes` аби розробники, що користуються ними, знали, інакше ті нові зміни можуть критичний розлад в програми цих розробників.

Comment: `backward incompatible changes` також ламають опосередкновано, тобто зімни в, наприклад, бібіліотеці кладуть підпрограми, які її використовують.

Comment: @improbable, `breaking changes` (в контексті [семантичного версіонування](https://semver.org/)) - це те саме, що `changes that are not backwards compatible`. Ці зміни самі по собі не "ламають" систему, система ламається, тому, що змінена API є несумісною з попередньою версією.

Comment: @improbable, чи правильно я Вас розумію: різниця між _backward incompatible_ і _breaking_ полягає в намірах розробника: якщо він навмисне прибирає частину можливих кейсів використання (бо, не зламавши старе, іноді важко побудувати нове), то це _backward incompatible_, а якщо це виходить в результаті помилки (а він цього не збирався робити), то це _breaking_ — так?

Comment: @Sasha Так, зазвичай це так.

Comment: @improbable виходить, що ні. Щойно прочитав у вельми шановній книзі по C#, що виправлення багу в C# з 4 на 5 версію була breaking change. Це було усвідомлене виправлення багу при захоплені змінної цикло в *foreach*. Так цю зміну назвали автори книги *C# 7.0 in a Nutshell* на 157 сторінці.

Comment: _Technically, this is a breaking change because recompiling a
C# 4.0 program in C# 5.0 could create a different result. In
general, the C# team tries to avoid breaking changes; however
in this case, a “break” would almost certainly indicate an
undetected bug in the C# 4.0 program rather than intentional
reliance on the old behavior._

Comment: @Yola, мені теж здається, що суто технічно різниці немає. Але, можливо, improbable правий, що є різниця в акцентах. _Breaking_ — це таке більш загальнолюдське, тоді як _backward incompatible_ дехто може сприймати лише в контексті взаємодії з ін. автоматичними системами, а не з людьми (наче це лише про API/ABI, але не про UI). Наприклад, коли встановили нові автоматичні вимикачі світла з датчиком руху й при цьому прибрали можливість вмикати/вимикати світло вручну (а в частині кейсів це зручніше), я для себе називаю це якраз _зворотньо несумісною_ зміною — але скільки % людей так це називають?

Comment: Перефразую. Це не ЗАВЖДИ одне і те саме, хоча в вищеназваних випадках це синоніми, погоджуюся.

Comment: @improbable, по-моєму, це якраз завжди те саме, але з різними акцентами (як-от _мавпа_ й _примат_) — але не буду сперечатися, можливо, я помиляюся.

Answer (score 3):

- **Зламувальна зміна** - як така, що призначена щось ламати.
- **Зламівна зміна** - як така, що може зламати.

Більше теорії у статті [Процесові прикметникі в науковій мові](https://r2u.org.ua/node/162), пункт 2.

Як варіант, за аналогією з *попсуй-майстер*, який псує, що йому не даш зробити. можна сказати **зламай-зміна**, зміна, яка ламає коли її застосовуєш.

Answer (score 2):

Джерело https://translate.google.com.ua/#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=uk&text=break

**break**

> дієслово
>
> separate or cause to separate into pieces as a result of a
>   blow, shock, or strain.
>
> "the rope broke with a loud snap"
>
> синоніми:
>   shatter smash crack snap fracture fragment splinter fall to bits fall
>   to pieces split burst bust

Джерело https://grammarway.com/ua/ing

> Закінчення -ing у дієслів слугує для утворення форми дієприкметника
>   теперішнього часу (Present Participle), що також використовується для
>   утворення граматичних часів групи Continuous, та форми Gerund. -Ing
>   також використовується в якості суфікса для утворення іменників та
>   прикметників від дієслів. Так як закінчення -ing змінює частину мови,
>   до якого належить слово, питання до цього слова змінюється з «що
>   робити?» на «що? який? як?».

Отже що ми маємо.

1. Слово break означає щось розбити на частинки.
2. ing - "який?" - той, що зараз розбиває щось на частинки.
3. Мова йде про зміну частини програмної системи. Тобто про код. Однина.
4. До чого може призвести зміна частини коду? До зламу програмної системи.

Також можна почитати https://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=46694&page=1473.

Висновок 1:
- зламна зміна.

Висновок 2:
Уявіть, що ви програміст. Ви зробили зміну в коді, що призвела до проблем у цілій програмній системі. Посипалися помилки звідусіль. Ви вже пів доби петраєте щоб його такого зробити, чи що ви накоїли, що воно все розсипалося на частини і вам не вдається усе зібрати до купи.
... і тут заходить замовник
... коли він це все побачить, то що він зробить з програмістом?

Отже правильна відповідь: карколомна зміна.

Comment: Мені здається, що коли ми кажемо *зламна зміна*, то дія спрямована на зміну, а не на код, тоді як ламається код.

Comment: Є різниця між "зламана зміна" і "зламна зміна". Зверніть увагу. Зміна яка? - зламна. Та, що щось зламала. Внаслідок якої щось зламалось. Зміна яка? зламана. Та, що не змінює. Або робить це неправильно.

Comment: Вода яка? - питна. Та, яку можна пити. Якщо ви хочете сказати, що зміна щось може зламати, то тоді можна спробувати *зламувальна зміна*. [Читанка на тему.](https://r2u.org.ua/node/162) Див. пункт 2.

Comment: Теж спочатку був подумав про _карколомну зміну_, але надто вже якось помпезно воно звучить.

Comment: @Sasha як щодо _кодоломних_?

Comment: @Yola, ідея хороша, але вони радше **поведінко**ломні, ніж кодоломні.

Comment: @Sasha а чи не можна просто *ломна зміна*?

Comment: @Yola, так, по-моєму, дуже логічна ідея. (Тим більше, що я подумав, що мій попередній коментар щодо поведінколомних не на 100% точний — ще можуть бути інтерфейсоломні й т.ін.) Хоча, наскільки воно приживеться, хтозна.

Answer (score 2):

Після обговорення в коментарях до відповіді Андрія Іванченко, пропоную ще один варіант:

- поведінколомна зміна
- кодоломна зміна
- інтерфейсоломна зміна
- білдоломна/збірколомна зміна
- кар'єроломна зміна
- ...

Але фактично, *поведінколомна* можна перекласти як *behavior breaking*, *кодоломна* як *code breaking*, то виходить, що можна спробувати перекласти просто як *ломна*. Отже, **ломна зміна**.

Answer (score 0):

На основі чудових відповідей од пана Yola, пропоную вашій увазі:

- [Фатальні](http://sum.in.ua/s/fataljnyj) зміни(-а)

> 1. Неминучий, невідворотний.
> 2. Який зумовлює, визначає характер (звичайно негативний, небажаний) наступних дій, перебігу подій.

Здебільшого це синононім до запропонованого, проте коротший та ніби як універсальний.

Comment: + критичні зміни, утім за СУМ-ом не найкращий варіант

Comment: По-моєму, це не те. Breaking change застосовується не лише до змін, які _обов'язково_ щось зламають, а радше до змін, які за своєю природою _спроможні_ на це; у випадку фатального в 2-му значенні ж навпаки — зверніть увагу, що всі наведені у словнику приклади кажуть про речі, які _вже відбулися_ (тобто серйозні наслідки яких _уже_ відомі). Та й конотація не та — наче щось погане.

Comment: @Sasha "...у випадку фатального в 2-му значенні ж навпаки — зверніть увагу, що всі наведені у словнику приклади кажуть про речі, які вже відбулися (тобто серйозні наслідки яких уже відомі)."

Приклад 1:
"...Основним месиджем Еко є думка про те, що варто лише повірити у змову, як вона починає існувати насправді. І тоді вже важко зупинити ті фатальні наслідки, до яких вона неодмінно призведе...." Джерело: https://molbuk.ua/vnomer/kultura/25161-zakokhanijj-u-serednovichchja.html

Comment: @Sasha 
"Це питання дуже серйозне, бо ця ціна може мати фатальні наслідки для суверенітету України в майбутньому. І це величезний ризик." https://lb.ua/world/2010/12/29/79292_vneshnyaya_politika_itogi_2010_god.html 
Звернув, утім прошу зверніть увагу як воно в житті викоростовуються.

Comment: @Sasha
"Та й конотація не та — наче щось погане." найближчі до цього слова синоніми: серйозні, наслідки, помилки. А беручу до уваги, що ця конструкція не громіздка, НМД вона одна з найкращих, бо описує ситуацію та інтуїтивно зрозуміла. Важко назвати аргумент мов конотація не та.

Comment: @Sasha оперуючи, наведеними мною прикладами, я погоджуюсь з вашим твердженням "...Breaking change застосовується не лише до змін...". НМД для програмного забезпечення це гарний варіант який судячі з реалій його використання та змісту має право на життя.